# JavaFX refetch observablelist from database

Tags: javafx, observable

I need to show a custom made list of nodes from a database table that is frequently updated from external sources.

When changes are made to the database, the list needs to be updated on the screen accordingly.

For this I have implemented an ObservableList with an onChanged method that should check for changes and rebuild the custom list.

I my case the onChanged method will never fire when new data is added in the database, only when changes are made on the fly to the already defined ObservableList.

How can i let the ObservableList know when new data exists in the database ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is polling the database not an option?  I am not aware of any RDBMS that utilizes any push model with a connection (push to client).  If I had to hack one - I would be writing a trigger on the table to detect changes, and react accordingly.

Comment: I have written a timer function that refetches the data every x seconds and rebuilds the gui nodes accordingly.
If i would update only the data, the observablelist would be replaced and the changes would not be noticed by the onChanged method, so i had to rebuild the gui completely.

Answer (score 0):

Given your answer to jkaufmann it seems you need to change your logic.

Instead of rebuilding ObservableList each time you need to calculate the difference with new data and update ObservableList with new/removed data.